# Android custom row layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Sorry in advance I need to include a few pictures to make my problem a little easier to understand.  I am using a linear layout for my custom rows and it is giving me lots of trouble trying to get the rows to look how I want.  Currently it looks like this

[image: Curent view]

Please forgive the quick paint picture I am about to show but it is how I would like the layout to look.

[image: desired look]

I would like to add the name textbox above the dog picture, and a time stamp textbox above each of the 1 and 2.  Whenever I try to add textboxes to display this it really messes with the layout.  The textbox above the dog picture always wants to go to the right or left of the dog image and push the image to the middle of the page and the buttons get spread out further.  I do not have much experience with this layout I typically do relative layout where I can drag and drop pieces.  Any advise or help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:id="@+id/dogimage"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:background="@drawable/dogpic"
    android:onClick="sendProfile"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:id="@+id/dog1num1"
    android:background="@drawable/num1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="NumberOne"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:id="@+id/dog1num2"
    android:background="@drawable/num2"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="NumberTwo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your imageview/textview combo in a LinearLayout. And you should set the imageButton using src, not background. Do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dogimage"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="sendProfile"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/dogpic" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Timestamp 1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/dog1num1"
                android:layout_width="75dip"
                android:layout_height="75dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="NumberOne"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/num1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Timestamp 1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/dog1num2"
                android:layout_width="75dip"
                android:layout_height="75dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="NumberOne"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/num2" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you that solution worked for the formatting I never would have came up with using multiple linear layouts.  I made them as backgrounds because doing as a src made the buttons have a grey boarder around them.

Comment: For the grey border, use android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"